# Bootstrap 2 - Collapsed responsive menu logo and toggle on same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Unfortunately, I'm stuck using Bootstrap 2 for this project. I'm struggling to have both the logo (`.brand`) and navigation toggle on the same line once my navbar has collapsed to the 'phone' level.

I've tried changing the `.row` to `.row-fluid`, however the `.span6` elements are still collapsing and spanning the entire width of the navbar once it goes down to 'phone' size.

Here's the markup I currently have:

```
<div id="header-row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
              <!--LOGO-->
              <div class="span3"><a class="brand" href="/"><img src="img/logo.png"/></a></div>
              <!-- /LOGO -->

            <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->  
              <div class="span9">
                <div class="navbar  pull-right">
                  <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li<?php if($current_file == 'index.php') {echo ' class="active"';}?>><a href="/">Home</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/#payback-time">Payback Time</a></li>
                        <li<?php if($current_file == 'funding.php') {echo ' class="active"';}?>><a href="/funding.php">Funding Options</a></li>
                        <li<?php if($current_file == 'supply-and-installation.php') {echo ' class="active"';}?>><a href="/supply-and-installation.php">Supply and Installation</a></li>
                        <li<?php if($current_file == 'contact.php') {echo ' class="active"';}?>><a href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>

                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I also have some custom navbar properties set by the theme I'm working with:

```
#header-row{
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

#header-row .navbar{margin:10px 0 0 0;}

#header-row .navbar .navbar-inner{
    border:none;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

#header-row .navbar .navbar-inner ul.nav > li > a{
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: #90c57b;
}
#header-row .navbar .navbar-inner ul.nav li.active a{
    color: #333;
}
```

[Live code demo](http://crf.jamesallison.co/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is follow the bootsrap navbar structure.  Right now your logo is outside of the navbar so it is displaying as a block element and so is the navbar.  Here is a working example of how to set up a bootstrap 2 navbar.  Your css should work the same with it but you may need to restyle a few things but not sure plug it in and give it a try.

```
<div id="header-row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="http://crf.jamesallison.co/img/logo.png" /></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav  pull-right" role="navigation">
              <li <?php if($current_file == 'index.php') {echo ' class="active"';}?>><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/#payback-time">Payback Time</a></li>
              <li <?php if($current_file == 'funding.php') {echo ' class="active"';}?>><?php if($current_file == 'funding.php') {echo ' class="active"';}?><a href="/funding.php">Funding Options</a></li>
              <li <?php if($current_file == 'supply-and-installation.php') {echo ' class="active"';}?>><a href="/supply-and-installation.php">Supply and Installation</a></li>
              <li <?php if($current_file == 'contact.php') {echo ' class="active"';}?>><a href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
       </nav> <!-- /navbar-end -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should keep the logo and the menu hamburger on the same line at mobile screen sizes